# Position elements with the div tag

Tags: css, dreamweaver, html

```
<div class="HeaderLink" id="Home">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  

<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
<title>MDB1</title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Index.css" />  
</head>  
<body id="HeaderFive">  
<div class="HeadPanelElement" lang="en" id="HeadPanel"> <a href="Blog" id="HeaderOne" title="Blog link" target="_self" class="HeadPanelElement">Blog</a>  
<a href="Videos" id="HeaderTwo" title="Video's link" target="_self" class="HeadPanelElement">Videos</a>  
<a href="Okay" id="HeaderThree" title="Homepage link" target="_self" class="HeadPanelElement">Home</a>  
<a href="Contact" id="HeaderFour" title="Contact link" target="_self" class="HeadPanelElement">Contact</a>  
<a href="About MDB1" id="HeaderFive" title="About MDB1 link" target="_self" class="HeadPanelElement">About MDB1</a> </div>  
</body>  
</html>  
</div>  


@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.HeadPanelElement{
position: absolute;  
width: 10%;  
left: -10%;  
}  
#HeadPanel{
left: 15%;  
width: 100%;  
height: 100%;  
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;  
border: dashed;  
border-color: #C00;  
border-width: 2px;  
font-size: 1em;
```

Intentions are for the page to layout like this [image]

Why aren't the position attributes working?

Comment: You have posted far less CSS than would be required to do this.

Comment: I meant for the head line above the MDB1 box.

Comment: you cannot have <div> outside of <body> (<div class="HeaderLink" id="Home">  is even before <html>)

Comment: ..why are you wrapping `<div>` around `<html>`?

Comment: @Malaken:  You need to [validate your code](http://validator.w3.org/) and learn about proper [HTML document structure](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial1/4.html) in no particular order.

Comment: You need to [validate your code](http://validator.w3.org/) and learn about proper [HTML document structure](http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial1/4.html) in no particular order.

Comment: @Jonathon bdparrish answered the questioned. This one is more specific

Comment: @Sparky672 How do those affect the layout?

Comment: @Malaken:  Open tags, stray tags, improperly placed tags, and extra tags can **all seriously affect your layout**

Comment: @Malaken:  When I made my first comment you had wrapped your entire `<html>` element inside a `<div>`.  You still have improper nesting: `<body><div></body></html></div>`

Comment: Don't you think Malaken is referring to div#HeadPanel when he refers to the "head." You may be criticizing him unjustly.

Comment: @Azmisov:  What he meant was unclear but I am only looking at the HTML he posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quick to do ...

```
#HeadPanel
{
    display: inline;
    width: 100%;
}

.HeadPanelElement
{
    width: 10%;
    /* or 
    padding: 10px; */
}
```

the real factor here is the display: inline; which will layout the div in a side by side fashion.

Comment: If I would like to position each anchor like the picture would I use left or right on each of their ID's?

Comment: @Malaken, so to move an inner element left or right define the parent container to hve absolute position. #HeadPanel { position: absolute; }, but don't truly position it you just want to establish absolute position, and then you can do relative position on child elements of this container.  .HeadPanelElement { position: relative; left: 15%; }.  The relative position works on the first establishment of absolute position in the parent containers or the DOM if none is defined.

Answer (score 2):

You are using 'left:' but you didn't include 'position:absolute'? Try that maybe it might help.

Comment: Where would I add the absolute position?

Answer (score 2):

For declarations like `left` and `top` to make any sense, you need to apply them to positioned elements:

```
#foo {
  position:absolute;
  top:10%;
  left:25%;
}
```

Your elements don't appear to have be positioned as `absolute` or `relative`.

There are many other problems with your markup as well that will cause many, many problems. All of your markup should go within the body tag:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Foo Example</title>
    <style type="text/css">
      #foo { 
        position:absolute; 
        top:10%; left:10%; 
        background:yellow;
        padding:10px 20px;
        border:1px solid #000;
        color:#000; 
        width:30% 
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <!-- all markup goes here -->
    <div id="foo">Hello World</div>
    <!-- all markup goes here -->
  </body>
</html>
```

Online Demo: http://jsbin.com/efukol/edit

Comment: Where would I add the absolute position?

Comment: @Malaken I've updated my example with the appropriate styles.

Answer (score 2):

`position: absolute;` will help you get that *interesting* layout.

Comment: Where would I add the absolute position?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things going on here:

1. The A element is inline, and things will sit right next to each other, like BlogVideosHomeContactAbout MDB1, as I am sure you have already seen.
2. This LOOKS like a list or menu, so use the appropriate markup. List markup would be best, or if you want to try HTML5, there is already the NAV element with is specifically for that purpose.
3. I notice that you are not using URLs in the a elements.  It is better to use something which will not generate a 404 on the server.
4. Why are you bothering with target="_self" unless you are using frames, and if that is the case, please Google for Frames are Evil.  If not, then A) _self is redundant, B) if you are using a Strict doctype, the target attribute is deprecated for accessibility reasons.
5. Naming your CSS file index.css might get you in trouble if the server is configured to use index. with ANY suffix to as the default page.  Better would be something like style.css.

Now to get these things going across, you can go a few ways:

```
/* CSS using line list markup */
#HeadPanel ul {list-style-type:none;}
#HeadPanel ul li {display:inline; padding:.25em 1em .25em 1em}

/* CSS using floats list markup */
#HeadPanel ul {list-style-type:none;}
#HeadPanel ul li {display:block;float:left;margin: 0 .1em 0 .1em;padding:.25em;}
#HeadPanel ul li a {display:block; /*what ever else you want to do */}
```

Comment: What does ul, li, and a after the ID name denote?

Comment: HeadPanel ul - any ul after HeadPanel, and HeadPanel ul li is any li following a ul after HeadPanel, and HeadPanel ul li a is any a element following li, following UL following HeadPanel id.