# Div layout in the head of an HTML page

Tags: css, html

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Position elements with the div tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462236/position-elements-with-the-div-tag)

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">  
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">  
<head>  
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />  
<title>MDB1</title>  
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="Index.css" />    
</head>  
<body>  
<div class="HeadPanelElement" lang="en" id="HeadPanel"> <a href="Blog" id="HeaderOne" title="Blog link" target="_self" class="HeadPanelElement">Blog</a>  
<a href="Videos" id="HeaderTwo" title="Video's link" target="_self" class="HeadPanelElement">Videos</a>  
<a href="Okay" id="HeaderThree" title="Homepage link" target="_self" class="HeadPanelElement">Home</a>  
<a href="Contact" id="HeaderFour" title="Contact link" target="_self" class="HeadPanelElement">Contact</a>  
<a href="About MDB1" id="HeaderFive" title="About MDB1 link" target="_self" class="HeadPanelElement">About MDB1</a> </div>  
</body>  
</html>  
</div>  


@charset "utf-8";
/* CSS Document */

.HeadPanelElement{
width: 20%;  
}  

#HeadPanel{
left: 15%;  
width: 100%;  
height: 100%;  
font-family: Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;  
border: dashed;  
border-color: #C00;  
border-width: 2px;  
font-size: 1em;  
display: inline;
```

}

Intentions are for the Head to layout like this [image]

How do i offset each "Header'Numeral'"?

This seems to have no effect:
    #HeaderOne{
        left: 10%;
        width: 20%;
    }

Edit* Where would I add the absolute position?

Comment: You appear to have asked this question less than an hour ago, and accepted an (incorrect) answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6462236/position-elements-with-the-div-tag